# Проверка формы на наличие пробелов и русских букв

Tags: регистрация, php, html, form, форма

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли функции и какие могут проверить в php наличие пробелов и русских букв. Например, нужно написать логин и он должен состоять только из латиницы, исключая пробелы, русские буквы, всякие точки и запятые. Может быть есть даже с ajax'ом?

Answer (score 2):

Проверять какие-то данные формы нужно регуляркой, например для пароля:

```
$preg = '/[a-zA-Z_0-9]+/';
$check = preg_match($preg, $_POST['password']);
if($check == true) {
    //true будет только если в строке будут строго
    //анг.буквы, числа и нижнее подчеркивание
}
else {
    //в противном случае будет false
}
```

Это проверка на сервере, на клиенте все делается примерно также:

```
var password = document.getElementById("password").value; //получаем значение пароля
var passwordPreg = /[a-zA-Z_0-9]/; //наша регулярка...
if(passwordPreg.test(password) === true) {
    //пароль корректен
}
else {
   //пароль некоректен...
}
```

Важно понимать что проверки на клиенте недостаточно и она делается лишь для удобства пользователей, т.е. даже реализовав проверку на клиенте любые данные обязаны перепроверяться сервером.
Естественно можно написать проверяющий скрипт на сервере и спрашивать у него аяксом, но валидация написаная на клиенте работает быстрее(что логично собственно)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/^([a-z]|\d|_)+$/i', $_POST['password'])) {
// корректный пароль, содержит только буквы латинского алфавита разных регистров, цифры и подчеркивания.
} else {
// не корректный пароль
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Неверная регулярка. Например, для `qwerty123ДЯдяВова` будет `TRUE`, потому что `preg_match` найдет в строке `qwerty123`